# Xeon E5 2683 V4 vs Xeon Bronze 4206 for DB server

Tags: server, intel

Need a new Server for MySQL DB.

Should I go for

- Xeon 4206 6 core CPU X 2 CPU's or
- Xeon E5 2683 V3/2680 V4/2683 V4 X 2 CPU's
- Xeon W 1270/1370P (Technically an I9, but higher clocks.)
  With Quad NVME Drives in Raid 10.

Database comprises of ~6000+ tables, dynamically created across multiple schemas.

Load on DB would be 300-500+ queries continuously. No Complex Joins but the retrieval would comprise of ~2000-60000 records per query.

Considerations.

- The purpose of it being a DB server should be fulfilled. Going for upgrade as the current DB performance is poor.
- Its clearly evident that my choices are constrained by the expendable cash i have. Hence, no exorbitant recommendations please.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are buying new machines, why not going for AMD CPUs. More cores per dollar ratio.

If you insist on going with Intel's platform, I'll highly advice using Xeon W 1x70 series (out in 2021) therefore faster RAM support.

PS: For proper DB performance, indexes etc.. Go for proper amount of RAM depending on your database's size.

Comment: Epyc's seem to be overheating. As I intend to run at max CPU utilization allowed levels, I am worried. Do correct me if i am wrong, so i can take a second look at AMD processors.

Comment: Considered Ryzen 5800X and 5900X with ECC Ram too, but they seem to be overheating just while running some benchmarks, which take ~10 minutes. How would they pare if i run them for ~18hrs X 7days a week X 365 days a year?